# My bootstrap front-end for a nodejs/express app keeps breaking

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I have created a web application with NodeJS/Express that utilizes bootstrap on the front end (using EJS pages as the view engine) and I am not sure as to why the boostrap pages toggle from working to not working. While the rest of my style buttons are fine, I have created nav-bars and other widgets on the front-end with bootstrap but I am not able to click on the nav-bar dropdown or use some of my buttons to enable GET and POST requests on my app. Why is this happening? It keeps toggling from working and not working and I am not sure why. I can include code references if needed

Comment: References would help. I would also try isolating the issue to see what could potentially be causing it by removing/commenting out code or using snippet editors to test to see what the potential issue is.

Comment: How could we tell if we don't see any of your source code?  Stack Overflow may be good, but it doesn't run on telepathy.